# What mechanism do async tasks use in ASP.Net MVC 4.0?

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the mechanism behind async tasks in MVC 4? How is it related to normal threading? Please provide detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in `async` and `await` keywords, you might find this [Channel 9 interview with Anders Hejlsberg](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-Async) interesting.

Also, take a look at: [this PDC video](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/PDC/PDC10/FT09/).

Answer (score 1):

As already indicated before, `async` keyword is part of .Net. For better implementation of asynchronous programming, Microsoft has released several CTPs for this and it will be out of the box on .Net 4.5 AFAIK.

Below article is helpful as well :

http://www.juliencorioland.net/Archives/en-aspnet-mvc-4-asynchronous-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a single ASP.NET page request is handled by a single thread. After the thread sends the response, it returns to the ASP.NET thread pool.

When you use `async`/`await` (or asynchronous pages), the thread handling the request marks the request as incomplete and then returns to the ASP.NET thread pool. When the awaitable completes later, an ASP.NET thread is assigned to run the rest of the method.

More specifically, `async`/`await` by default use `SynchronizationContext`. See [my MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Async Tasks is a feature of .NET, not of ASP.NET  MVC 4. They work the same in ASP.NET as they do elsewhere within .NET.

Comment: Thanks for information. I sam async Task<ActionResult> in MVC 4. So I raised this question.